# Stripe webhook events, customer.subscription.created and customer.subscription.updated are triggered at the same time

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using nextjs 13 api and stripe, after creating customer subscription two events are triggered at the same time, customer.subscription.created and customer.subscription.updated.
I need one event `customer.subscription.created` because I'm creating subscription.

```js
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret)

switch (event.type) {
case 'customer.subscription.created':
    console.log('subscription created');
    break
case 'customer.subscription.updated':
    console.log('subscription updated');
    break
default:
    console.warn(`Unhandled event type: ${event.type}`);
    break
}
```

I'm getting two events at the same time
I need only one event `customer.subscription.created` instead of updated and created at the same time on create subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Events are generated when things happen in your Stripe account. You didn't share much details but it's likely that you have code first creating the Subscription and then doing something to it such as confirming the PaymentIntent. That latter step would move the Subscription's `status` from `incomplete` to `active` for example which would trigger that `customer.subscription.updated` Event.

Overall, your code has to be resilient to getting multiple Events often out of order. This is covered in Stripe's docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#event-ordering).
You likely should look at the sequence of Events and what changed in `previous_attributes` to understand what's causing this and then find a way in your code to handle this.